# How to get average training speed in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I used tensorflow 1 (estimator), there is a tfevent file recording events per `log_step_count_steps`, including the `global_step/sec`. I used that to calculate the average training speed.

I wonder what's the counterpart in tensorflow2?

Thanks,
Muyang

Comment: Hi! Have you checked the update on Estimators yet.You can still use estimator in 1.x mode.                                                                  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We are actually migrating over to the Keras API. I wonder if the global_step/sec is still available there?

Comment: In Tensorflow/Keras 2.x versions , you can measure performance of model through different metric in model.compile() method . you can also use model.evaluate() to evaluate your model with respect to Dataset. Attaching Reference below ;           https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate             https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/sample_size_estimate/        https://neptune.ai/blog/keras-metrics